# PHP / MySQL: Error in multiple delete, only latest ID deleted

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, bootstrap-4

I got some problems with my code. I want to delete multiple data from MySQL database that populate from Select Option.

Example: I select data with id 5, 2, 4, then press the delete button, it only deletes the latest id which is 5.

Can I know what is the problem? Below is my code:

index.html

```
    <?php

    include("configPDO.php");

    $smt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM frame_list ORDER BY framework_name ASC");
    $smt->execute();
    $results = $smt->fetchAll();


    ?>

<form method="post" id="multiple_select_form">
    <select name="framework[]" id="framework" class="form-control selectpicker" data-live-search="true" multiple>
        <?php foreach ($results as $row2): ?>
            <option value= <?php echo $row2["framework_id"]; ?>><?php echo $row2["framework_name"];?></option>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </select>
<br><br>
<input type="hidden" name="framework_id" id="framework_id" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />
</form>

   <script>

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();

    $('#framework').change(function(){
    $('#framework_id').val($('#framework').val());
    });

    $('#multiple_select_form').on('submit', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if($('#framework').val() != '')
    {
    var form_data = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        url:"delete.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:form_data,
        success:function(data)
        {
        //console.log(data);
        $('#framework_id').val('');
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', '');
        alert(data);
        }
    })
    }
    else
    {
    alert("Please select framework");
    return false;
    }
    });
    });


    </script>
```

delete.php

```
    <?php

    include("configPDO.php");

    $smt = $conn->prepare("DELETE FROM frame_list WHERE framework_id = '".$_POST["framework_id"]."'");
    $smt->execute();

    if($smt){

        echo "Data DELETED";
    }else{
        echo "Error";
    }


    ?>
```

Appreciate it if anyone can solve my problem.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your `$_POST["framework_id"]` should be an array, since it is a multiple select. Therefore you should use `DELETE FROM myTable WHERE id IN ".$_POST['framework_id']."` to delete all values from that array

Answer (score 0):

this is where framework id got overwritten:

```js
$('#framework').change(function(){
    $('#framework_id').val($('#framework').val());
});
```

delete.php will only run when your ajax request send(in this case, when you click submit button).

so maybe you'll want to pass several id at a single request if you want delete them at the same time. or you may want to delete them one by one by sending the ajax request each time you choose a id.

Comment: then? can give the full answer?

Comment: join the selected id will do the work.  `$('#framework_id').val(selected.join(','))`

Comment: also, you cant get these selected id on submit callback, the framework_id input is not necessary.